# SQL timedeltas and .... i think ineed to do self joining?

Tags: sql

my table has columns

```
 Group1  Group2  startdate enddate
```

The general format of the table is such group2 has unique IDs, and they are clumped together in batches that share a group1 ID, and the start/end dates correspond to the Group2. Some data might look like,

```
 Group1  Group2  startdate enddate
   1        51     20120101
   1        23     20120201
   2        54     20120101  20120201
   2        99     20120215
   3        21     20120201 20120301
```

The dates arent necessarily the first of months, it was just easy that way.

I need a single `SELECT` statement that looks for a particular event: when a group2 has an enddate, then 'soon' after (lets say, less than a month), a different Group2 has a start date with the same Group1. I.E. a customer cancels and re-subscribes under a different group2 but the same group one. The 'answer' for the sample data would be `99`

If a single select statement is impossible, please let me know why and suggest how to do it with multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More infomation is probably needed to be precise, but I have a feeling this is what you need to figure the rest out for yourself.  This solution makes two assumtions

1. Group1 is your unique CustomerID (not unique in this table).
2. You don't care how long after the Cust cancels until they resubscribe.

```
select      SD.Group1,
            MT.Group2,
            SD.startdate
from        MyTable MT
            join (
                select      Group1,
                            max(startdate) as startdate
                from        MyTable
                where       Group1 = 2
                group by    Group1
            ) SD on SD.Group1 = MT.Group1
                and SD.startdate = MT.startdate
```

If you want to use a separate customer ID, then

1. add cutsomer ID to the subslelect's select list
2. change your where clause to reflect its use
3. add it to the join on clause

```
                and SD.CustomerID = MT.CustomerID
```

To limit the amount of time from cancel to resubscribe requires a slightly more significant edit. If you need it I'll try to post it.

If the posted answers don't solve it, post more information including code clips, table structure, and more of you thoughts on how it should work.

Comment: Yea, there was a syntax of self joining i was getting wrong. Your answer seems to have cleared that up.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  MyTable t
 WHERE  enddate IS NULL
   AND  EXISTS(
                    SELECT  1
                      FROM  MyTable
                     WHERE  Group2 <> t.Group2
                       AND  Group1 = t.Group1
                       AND  enddate BETWEEN t.startdate AND DATEADD(month, -1, t.startdate)
                       AND  enddate IS NOT NULL
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table2 table(startdate datetime, enddate datetime, group1 int, group2 int)

insert into @table2 
select '20120101', null, 1, 51
UNION
select '20120101', null, 1, 23
UNION
select '20120101', '20120201', 2, 54
UNION
select '20120215', null, 2, 99
UNION
select '20120101', null, 3, 21

select a.group2 from @table2 a inner join @table2 b on a.group1 = b.group1 and b.enddate > DATEADD(mm, -1, a.startdate) and a.enddate is null
```